# Changed byte value solved this, but why? SAS: this range is repeated, or values overlap

Tags: sas, proc, sas-macro

My BI department just ran into the SAS error: this range is repeated, or values overlap.

I found some links they looked at and found that there was an error in a macro.
The error was that the length of a numeric variable byte value was changed from 7 to 6 bytes created this error.
Now when they changed it back to it's previous value everything is ok.

What is this behaviour all about? Are there some logic in this?

Comment: "this range is repeated, or values overlap" looks like an error from PROC FORMAT where start value is repeated or overlapped. So i guess they altered the value in some way that caused it look like an overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reducing the length of a variable from 7 to 6 bytes, some numbers might get "truncated". 7 bytes can store integers up to 35,184,372,088,832 while 6 bytes can store only integers up to 137,438,953,472. Decimal numbers should always be length 8. See [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm) for details.